# Supervision of minors - to what age?

Tags: united-states, minor

A program for children like a school or camp is required to supervise the children under their control.

Until what age is one required to provide supervision to minors?

Comment: Different ages for different types of supervision, I should think.  Does a program for 18-year-olds have any responsibilities with regard to the consumption of alcohol?

Answer (score 2):

This varies dramatically between states in the US.  [Here](http://www.latchkey-kids.com/latchkey-kids-age-limits.htm) is a list which shows minimum ages from None to 14 years old.

Comment: This list specifically is only meant to be applied in a home environment. Is it true that a camp or high school has no supervision responsibilities to children over 14?

Comment: I cant answer that, but I would guess the responsibilities would be to the kids parents rather then the state. In New Zealand there is no distinction in the law, but thats not the USA.

Comment: Note that Illinois' minimum age of 14 is a guideline.  The only states with hard limits are Maryland (8), New Mexico (11), North Carolina (8), and Oregon (10).